# Android block based OTA with recovery.img, cache.img, system.img, boot.img and userdata.img

Tags: android-source

I want to create a full block based OTA package for an android device.
With the default implementation for creating a OTA only boot.img and system.img files are inside the zip.

I wish to create a file with other required image files also in the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is far to broad to answer in detail, take a look at the following short draft to get you started:

You can start with adding your other .img files to your `target-files.zip` by adding cp commands for them in your `build/core/Makefile` in the `.PHONY: target-files-package` section.

Then modify the [ota_from_target_files.py](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files.py) to take your .imgs from the target-files.zip and add them to the ota.zip. The key functions here are: 
`input_zip.read(..) and output_zip.writestr(..)`

To replace your imgs during update you finally need to add commands to flash them to your `updater-script`. this would look like: `package_extract_file(cache.img, "path")`

Comment: The answer was helpful. I implemented this way only. I didn't added them as answer. But still trying to understand if there is any other way we can implement the process without modifying the **build/core/Makefile**